# netsuite suitetalk token based authentication USER_ERROR Invalid login attempt in second call

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

I am trying to call Netsuite Api from .NET using Netsuite SuiteTalk https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2018_1_0/netsuite.wsdl. Given a session, it works well on the `first invoke` however it throws `USER_ERROR Invalid Login Attempt` from `second invoke`. It is working if I create new session for each call.

```
using (var service = GetNewSession())
{
    // working
    search(service, code);
    // failed: USER_ERROR Invalid Login Attempt
    search(service, code);
}
```

The GREEN row is where the second invoke is `FAILED`. Not sure why column `Role` is empty.

[image]

Create a connection to Netsuite WS

```
static string accountId = "";
        static string consumerKey = "";
        static string consumerSecret = "";
        static string tokenId = "";
        static string tokenSecret = "";

        public static NetSuiteService GetNewSession()
        {
            // Force TLS 1.2
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            NetSuiteService service = new NetSuiteService();
            service.Timeout = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2;

            var wsDomainUrl = service.getDataCenterUrls(accountId).dataCenterUrls.webservicesDomain;
            var pathAndQuery = new Uri(service.Url).PathAndQuery;
            var uri = new Uri(wsDomainUrl + pathAndQuery).ToString();
            service.Url = uri;

            service.tokenPassport = CreateTokenPassport();

            return service;
        }
```

Create token passport:

```
    private static TokenPassport CreateTokenPassport()
    {
        
        string nonce = ComputeNonce();
        long timestamp = ComputeTimestamp();
        TokenPassportSignature signature = ComputeSignature(accountId, consumerKey, consumerSecret, tokenId, tokenSecret, nonce, timestamp);

        TokenPassport tokenPassport = new TokenPassport();
        tokenPassport.account = accountId;
        tokenPassport.consumerKey = consumerKey;
        tokenPassport.token = tokenId;
        tokenPassport.nonce = nonce;
        tokenPassport.timestamp = timestamp;
        tokenPassport.signature = signature;
        return tokenPassport;
    }
```

Compute Nonce:

```
    private static string ComputeNonce()
    {
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] data = new byte[20];
        rng.GetBytes(data);
        int value = Math.Abs(BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0));
        return value.ToString();
    }
```

Compute Timestamp:

```
    private static long ComputeTimestamp()
    {
        return ((long)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds);
    }
```

Compute signature:

```
    private static TokenPassportSignature ComputeSignature(string compId, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret,
                                    string tokenId, string tokenSecret, string nonce, long timestamp)
    {
        string baseString = compId + "&" + consumerKey + "&" + tokenId + "&" + nonce + "&" + timestamp;
        string key = consumerSecret + "&" + tokenSecret;
        string signature = "";
        var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(key);
        byte[] baseStringBytes = encoding.GetBytes(baseString);
        using (var hmacSha1 = new HMACSHA1(keyBytes))
        {
            byte[] hashBaseString = hmacSha1.ComputeHash(baseStringBytes);
            signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBaseString);
        }
        TokenPassportSignature sign = new TokenPassportSignature();
        sign.algorithm = "HMAC-SHA1";
        sign.Value = signature;
        return sign;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Checked with Netsuite support, it is by design the session is available for 1 netsuite call only.

Comment: Do you have references about this?

Comment: Nah. I had called their support to confirm.